# Discordjs: changing button style on click, interaction.edit is not a function, Interaction has already been acknowledged, not been sent or deferred

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have embed with buttons. When buttons are clicked `interactionCreate` event is triggered. It used to show red message `This interaction has failed`, because I don't want the bot to reply in chat each time a button is clicked, so I added
`buttonInteraction.deferUpdate();`
to prevent that.

Now the buttons work fine and the This interaction has failed doesn't appear.

However I'd like to change the style of a button that was pressed.

I tried to do

```
buttonInteraction.component.disabled = true; 
buttonInteraction.component.style = 3;
buttonInteraction.edit({component: buttonInteraction.component});
```

But I get a `TypeError: interaction.edit is not a function` error.

Changing it to `editReply` results in `Error [INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.` error:

```
buttonInteraction.component.disabled = true;
buttonInteraction.component.style = 3;
buttonInteraction.editReply({component: buttonInteraction.component});
```

Changing it to

```
buttonInteraction.update({component: buttonInteraction.component});
```

causes `DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.` error

I'm not sure what is wrong and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You might try using:

```js
buttonInteraction.message.edit({component: buttonInteraction.component});
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it got me `Error [INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.` error

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out:

In method that reacts to event:

```js
buttonInteraction.component.disabled = true;
buttonInteraction.component.style = "SUCCESS";
let allComponents = buttonInteraction.message.components;
await buttonInteraction.update({components: allComponents});
buttonInteraction.editReply();
```

And I removed `.deferUpdate` from the `client.on("interactionCreate")`

Some notes: I only managed to make a clicked button to update by passing all components on that message to the `.update` method. Couldn't figure out how to update that very button individually.